# 2 being irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/23}$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. I want to show that $2$ is irreducible in $R$.

I splitted $2\mathbb{Z}$ (as prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$) in $R$, got $(2)=(2,\theta)(2,\bar{\theta})$ with $\theta=\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}$ and $\bar{\theta}=\frac{1-\sqrt{-23}}{2}$. Now if $2=\alpha\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta$ non-unit, then wlog $(2,\theta)=(\alpha)$ and $(2,\bar{\theta})=(\beta)$. So the problem becomes whether $(2,\theta)$ is principal. Actually I found these two problems equivalent.

To show directly that $2$ is irreducible, I considered $Z[\omega]=Z[x]/(f(x))$ with $f(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^{22}$. Then it is equivalent to show that $f(x)h(x)+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for any $h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

To show that $(2,\theta)$ is not a pricipal ideal, suppose $(2,\theta)=(\alpha)$. I taked norm ${\rm N}={\rm N}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\omega]}$, got ${\rm N}(\alpha)=2^{11}$. I showed that $(2,\theta)$ is not a pricipal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ using this method, but got stuck in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.

I don't know how to continue in either approch. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of understanding the situation. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{23})$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the ideal generated by $2$ and $\theta$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ be any ideal lying above $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$, where $\theta:=\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}$. Then the following holds:
(i) $L/K$ is a field extension.
(ii) $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$, i.e., $\mathfrak{p}$ is inert in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$.
(iii) $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ are not principal ideals in their respective rings.
Let $2=ab,$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$. Now, $2\nmid 23$ and the order of 2 in $(\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z})^*$ is 11 (and also the degree of the extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is 22) implies that (2) splits into exactly 2 distinct primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$, one of them being $\mathfrak{q}$. Also, (2)=$(a)(b)$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ cannot be either of them (by (iii)) means that $\mathfrak{q}$ must divide one of $(a)$ or $(b)$. WLOG, let $\mathfrak{q}~|~(a)$ (that is $a$ is not a unit). Then the other prime divisor $\mathfrak{q}'$ of $(2)$ must be such that $\mathfrak{q}\mathfrak{q}'=(2)$. Thus $(b)=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$, i.e., $b\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]^*$.